# jQuery.validation rails gem submitting when there are errors present

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jQuery.validation rails gem, essentially the same as the plug in, and it should by default prevent my form from submitting if there are errors present. 
For some reason, it will submit even though I am staring at errors. 
Please let me know why because I have spent a ton of time on this!!

```
$('.edit_profile').validate({
rules: {
    'profile[first_name]': {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    'profile[last_name]': {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    'profile[location]': {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    'profile[birthday]': {
      check_date_of_birth: true,
      required: true
    },
    'profile[operating_system]': {
      required: true,
      minlength: 1
    },
    'profile[about_me]': {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 500
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: Try setting `debug: true` before the `rules` property. Then look in the console for what errors are happening.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the selector at the top is actually selecting the form element itself and not any wrapping `div` or something. Then, use the `name` property of each field you want to validate. It doesn't accept the syntax you're using.

If your HTML looks like this:

```
<form class="profile">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <input type="text" name="last_name" />
    ...
</form>
```

Then the correct way to validate will be:

```
$('.profile').validate({ // select the form
rules: {
    first_name: { // use the "name" property as the "key" for each rule
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    last_name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    ...
  }
});
```

[Here's the documentation.](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#rules)

Comment: The name values are right but they're created by rails (i believe), anyways that parts fine as long as you put quotes around the name you didn't assign.  I tried it that way before though, and my form had other issues because my form didn't like name: 'first_name', etc. 
Thank you though!